# EC2 dashboard mentions about a running instance, even when the instance is not running

Tags: amazon-ec2

EC2 dashboard mentions about a running instance, even when the instance is not running. I see a EBS volume also in a in-use status. I am confused, is the machine running or not?

Comment: I have been using console for years never it seem to be lying. BTW, how do you test that the running server is, _in fact_, not running?

Comment: Sometimes the servers do have hardware failures which cause them to show a running state but do not allow login. Best thing to do in this situation is to contact amazon via the forums and ask if they can look at your instance. Before making it public make sure that you really can't connect and that you didn't just lock yourself out somehow.

Comment: @Nishant - We usually login into the machine via SSH and it doesn't allow us to login.

Comment: @Nishant - Are you suggesting that I am lying here, I wouldn't be asking this question otherwise. Is there a way to attach images in stackoverflow?

Comment: @priya I don't mean that you're lying. All I wanted to know is how you're validating what you're saying. Yes, these is a way to attach an image. Click on edit. One of the icons above the text area is to attach image.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that happen when closing down an linux instance on the machine (with `shutdown now` from the command line).

If the console says that the instance is running even though you shut it down you should probably shut it down from the console (to avoid being billed).

Comment: I shut it down via the EC2 console and I still observe the same behavior. The EC2 instance shows as stopped, but the dashboard says its still running.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are problems with the hardware on the server. The instance is showing as running but you cannot connect and you cannot use any services on that instance. The best thing to do in this situation is post a message on EC2's forums and ask them to look at your instance.

They're usually pretty quick to respond though they don't make any grantees.  They can force the machine into a stopped state, whether or not they can fix the issue without you loosing your data will depend on what is actually wrong with the instance.

This happens from time to time with my instances as well.